# HQL : subtract days form Date to get new Date

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql

I have a field called `ebOpenUptoDays` and `StartDate` in my domain class called Training

now lets say

ebOpenUptoDays = 10 (Days)

StartDate = 30 Oct 2013

i want to get the date called `ebExpiryDate` from my HQL with following calculation

ebExpiryDate = StartDate - ebOpenUptoDays

ebExpiryDate  = 20 Oct 2013 (need in this format)

```
trainingList  = Training.executeQuery("SELECT ........... as ebExpiryDate from Training as t)
```

Comment: You can use formula for ebExpiryDate in your domain

Comment: is it not possible from HQL?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the three possible solutions:

1) Try using DATE(DATE_SUB(StartDate, INTERVAL '${ebOpenUptoDays}' DAY)) in formula in grails domain class

2) Try using projection in createCriteria e.g. 
//Supported in grails 2.1.0 or above i guess.

```
Training.createCriteria.list{
    projections{sqlProjection("DATE(DATE_SUB(start_date, INTERVAL 'eb_Open_Up_to_days DAY))",DATE)}
}
```

3) Try use [native sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088641/mapping-result-of-a-native-sql-query-to-grails-domain-class)

**EDIT: For supporting hql you need to create you own dialect and use this in you datasource.groovy (Not tested though)**

```
public class MyDialect extends MySQLInnoDBDialect{
      public myDialect() {
      super();
      registerFunction("date_add_interval", new SQLFunctionTemplate(Hibernate.DATE, "date_sub(?1, INTERVAL ?2 ?3)"));
      }
    }
```

then, DATE(DATE_SUB(StartDate, INTERVAL 'ebOpenUptoDays' DAY)) should work for you in hql.
Hope this helps!!!

Thanks

Comment: I have filed called ebOpenUptoDays in my database

Comment: I am sorry DATE_SUB is not supported by hql Updating my answer now

Comment: so where i need to create this MyDialect  class?? inside datasource.groovy??

Comment: No, Better way of doing would be if you can create it in src/groovy/pakage/MyDialect.groovy and specify this class as dialect in dataSource.groovy e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850955/configuring-postgres-in-grails

Comment: @monda was the answer helpful....please.....accept the answer if it solves your problem...Thanks